# Values from CheckBox are not getting to the controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of checkboxes on a page, however, their values are not getting to the controller.

`ListViewModel` is where all my models I need in this view. `Techniques` is a list of `Technique` from database. `Technique` has `TechiqueID` and `Type` as attributes.  `tech` is a bool array with the same size of techniques types

```
@model ListViewModel
 @foreach (var item in Model.Techniques ){
                <div>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.tech[item.TechniqueID]) 
                    @item.Type 
                </div>
            }
```

Any idea why `tech[]` is null in the controller? It should be on the controller `tech[0] = false`, `tech[1] = false` and so on.

Output:

```
<div>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Boolean field is required." id="tech_1_" name="tech[1]" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="tech[1]" type="hidden" value="false" /> 
   Slippers, Distracting Tasks
</div>
<div>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Boolean field is required." id="tech_2_" name="tech[2]" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="tech[2]" type="hidden" value="false" /> 
   Hallway Placement
</div>
```

Comment: What does the output HTML look like for your checkboxes?

Comment: You really need to provide the code for ListViewModel, as well as any nested types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that lists of controls need to be 0 based, and sequential.  Your first item is based on 1.

If you need to keep this, then you will need to write a custom model binder for this.  An easier solution might be to simply subtract one from the TechniqueID then add it back when you use it.

Another option would be to add a hidden field with a name of tech[0] and just ignore the first item in the list on post.

Answer (score 1):

You do not build your html properly. The model binder cannot bind input names like this. Please refer to this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), which explains how to do model binding to a list.
From article:

Html output that you are looking for:

```html
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    <input type="text" name="[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].DatePublished" value="2/23/1973" />

    <input type="text" name="[1].Title" value="Code Complete" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].Author" value="Steve McConnell" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].DatePublished" value="6/9/2004" />

    <input type="text" name="[2].Title" value="The Two Towers" />
    <input type="text" name="[2].Author" value="JRR Tolkien" />
    <input type="text" name="[2].DatePublished" value="6/1/2005" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Sample code to achieve this output:

```cs
<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>

  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Title) %>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Author) %>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].DatePublished) %> 

<% } %>
```